# Issues in installing Apache on CentOS 7

Tags: apache, centos

I have problems with installing Apache on CentOS 7. I got message 'GuessOS' ,'httpd.h' files couldn't found. But I found that GuessOS and httpd.h files are  in correct folders. So please help me to solve this problem..